# Generate automatically a PDF from a xls file when each cells are fill

Tags: excel, vba, pdf, xls

I begin in VBA code and i want to generate a PDF from a xls file.
this xls file is a schedule of the week with for each day fill by 0 or 1 like this :

| D1 | D2 | D3 | D4 | SUM | EXPECTED | VALIDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 0 | 1 | 1 | 4 | 4 | OK |

Then, i compute the sum and compare with the expected sum. If it's equal then the column validate is OK else it's KO.

Finally, i want to generate a PDF from this file, when the user fill for each DAY (D1,..,D4) then compute the validate column and export file in PDF if it's "OK"

I try this for the moment :

```
    Sub generate_PDF_()
    '
    ' generate_PDF_ Macro
    '
    
    Dim saveLocation As String
    saveLocation = "path/to/savefolder"
    
    Range("AG2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM((RC[-31]:RC[-1]))"
    Range("AI2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(RC[-2]=RC[-1],""OK"",""KO"")"
    
    If Range("AI2").Select = 'OK' Then
        .ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=saveLocation & "/attendance_sheet" & .ActiveSheet.Name & ".pdf"
        
End If
    
    End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 1):

If Range("AI2").Select = 'OK' Then -  this will not work as you think and use "OK" instead of 'OK'

Use the Worksheet_Change Event  to control the value. (You can use it in a worksheet module only)

```
    Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
         If Not (Intersect(Target, Range("AI2")) Is Nothing) Then
             If Target.Value2="OK" Then 
                  ... ' add your code
             End if
         End if
    End Sub
```

.Activesheet without "With Application ... end with" construction will give you an Error. Use Application.ActiveSheet

There are no reason to use Range.Select  method. Instead of:

```
    Range("AG2").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM((RC[-31]:RC[-1]))"
```

Use:

```
    Range("AG2").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM((RC[-31]:RC[-1]))"
```